# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute savefig in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am trying to display `plotly.express` bar chart in Flask. But it is giving `'Figure' object has no attribute savefig error`. The image gets displayed correctly while using `fig.show()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px

figs = px.bar(
    comp_df.head(10),
    x = "Company",
    y = "Staff",
    title= "Top 10 departments",
    color_discrete_sequence=["blue"],
    height=500,
    width=800
)
figs.savefig('static/images/staff_plot.png')
#    fig.show()
return render_template('plot.html', name='new_plot', url='static/images/staff_plot.png')
```

In `plot.html`, the image is displayed as below:

```
<img src={{ url}} >
```

Answer (score 6):

You have defined `figs` with the `px.bar()` method.

Per [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html#plotly.express.bar) `px.bar()` returns a `plotly.graph_objects.Figure` object.

Looking at this `plotly.graph_objects.Figure` class' documentation we can see all the methods available on this `plotly.graph_objects.Figure` class.
`show()` appears to be a valid method for this type of object. However there is no `savefig()` method for this class.
This is why `fig.show()` works and `fig.savefig()` doesn't work.

It looks like there is a `savefig()` method on the `matplotlib.pyplot` class as [documented here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html), however your `figs` object is an instance of `plotly.graph_objects.Figure` not `matplotlib.pyplot`.

If your goal is to write your `figs` object to a file, it looks like the documentation specifies 3 methods that provide this functionality:

`plotly.graph_objects.Figure`

- [write_html](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.write_html)
- [write_image](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.write_image)
- [write_json](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.write_json)

Try replacing:

`figs.savefig('static/images/staff_plot.png')`

with

`figs.write_image(file='static/images/staff_plot.png', format='.png')`

Comment: Thank you. While using write_image, I am getting error "Orca module required'

Comment: Thanks. The images are showing but the tooltips are not showing when I hover on a bar. Maybe because it is only a image but then it looks a bit less interactive

Comment: Sorry I can't help here. I've never actually used either of these libraries.

Comment: thanks, this just helped me, but I just realized that the format should be 'png' without dot(.)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `figs.savefig`, try to use `plt.savefig`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('static/images/staff_plot.png')
```